# Operations on two families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When it comes to families of sets, I have a difficulty comprehending how the sum and the intersection works when there are two (indexed) families of sets. Here is an example:
$$\bigcap\limits^{}_{t}(F_t\cap G_t) \subset \bigcup\limits^{}_{t} F_t \cap \bigcup\limits^{}_{t} G_t
 $$
where $ (F_t)_{t \in T}, (G_t)_{t \in T}  $ are families of sets.

How can I conceptualize this property? Do I intersect each set of two families  i.e. $ F_1\cap G_1$, and then interset all the intersections? Even if, how does it even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need are definitions:
$$\bigcap\limits^{}_{t \in A}F_t =\{x \colon \forall t \in A, x \in F_t  \}$$
$$\bigcup\limits^{}_{t \in A}F_t =\{x \colon \exists t \in A, x \in F_t  \}$$
Now using them and that $\forall$ is distributive against $\land$, we obtain,
$$x \in \bigcap\limits^{}_{t}(F_t\cap G_t) \Rightarrow (\forall t) (x \in F_t\cap G_t) \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow (\forall t) (x \in F_t \land x \in G_t) \Rightarrow (\forall t) (x \in F_t) \land (\forall t) (x \in G_t)\Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow x \in\bigcup\limits^{}_{t} F_t \cap \bigcup\limits^{}_{t} G_t$$

**Addition.**

Let's take $F_n=\left(-1,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $G_n=\left(-\frac{1}{n}, 1\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $E_n = F_n \cap G_n = \left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Considering left side gives example, that countable intersection of open sets can be not open.

Comment: Thank you for a proof! If I may have one more question: could you give a concrete example of how that property would work?

Comment: Wrote addition. Hope, you can manage right side also.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for help.